# Create stored procedure on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to create a stored Procedure in a Database (SQL Server)

```
    string query = "CREATE PROCEDURE  queryName AS BEGIN " + sqlCommand + " END";
    SqlConnection cnn;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    //builder["Provider"] = provider;
    builder["Server"] = @"Themis\DEV";

    builder["Integrated Security"] = "SSPI";
    string connection_string = builder.ConnectionString;

    cnn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);

    cnn.Open();


    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(queryName, cnn);
    sqlCmd.CommandText = query;
    sqlCmd.Connection = cnn;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get an Errormessage

> Incorrect syntax near INNER

The Procedure is like this

```
UPDATE description 
       INNER JOIN description1 
               ON description.resid_ = description1.resid_ 
SET    description.polish = [description1].[polish] 
WHERE  (description1.polish <> '') 
AND    (description1.polish <> ( '-' ));
```

Comment: I would suggest that you test your SQL on Server Management prior to making it programmatically. It's always easier to diagnose problems with your code when you know for a fact that your SQL is valid.

Comment: Apart from being invalid SQL, why are you doing a `JOIN` on `resid_` on the same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a valid `Update` using `Join` syntax in `SQL SERVER`. Try this way

```
UPDATE D 
SET    D.polish = [D1].[polish] 
FROM   description D 
       INNER JOIN description1 D1 
               ON D.resid_ = D1.resid_ 
WHERE  D1.polish <> '' 
       AND D1.polish <> '-';
```

Where clause can be simplified using `NOT IN`

```
Where D1.polish NOT IN ('','-')
```